# Streamhandler logging (stream=sys.stdout) Python

Tags: python, logging, telegram-bot

Help me please to write correctly logging function

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout,)

ENV_VARS = ['API_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID']

def check_tokens():
    for var in ENV_VARS:
        if var is None:
            logging.critical(f'Token {var} unavailible')
            raise exсeptions.NoValidTokenError(f'Token {var} unavailible')
```

the logging doesn't work
what am I missing?

Comment: The code you provided will never log anything since you are only logging something if any string in the list `ENV_VAR` is None (which none of the provided are). Given your variable names I would guess that you are trying to read Environment Variables with the given names. So you could try to change `if var is None:` to `if os.getenv(var) is None:`.

Comment: I previously assigned tokens to these variables like this
APP_TOKEN = os.getenv('API_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TG_TOKEN')

I have some written tests and they are the ones that fall with an error. "Make sure that in the absence of mandatory environment variables, the event is logged with the `CRITICAL` level."
so I think that there is some problem in logging)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for others to help you out since in the one you provided ENV_VAR is simply a list of strings and not variables like you say.

Comment: you were right, finally I understood this) TY